# How to update value of an dataframe if it satisfies a specific condition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

just need to know how can we update values inside a df with specific condition.
If my approach is wrong please suggest one

```
while (i<myList.length-1)
{
    j=1
        while(j<myList.length)
        {
            result  = sqrt(pow(myList(i)- myList(j),2) + pow(myList2(i) - myList2(j),2))
            if(result>=3.4)
                df3.withColumn("New_Id", col("id")+1)  // if the coundition satisfies I need to update the new value as 1,2,3, .... in the New_id column
           j=j+1;      
        }
    i=i+1
}
```

df3.show(10)
}

Comment: I think this is not the right approach. If you can specify some sample data and show what you are trying to do someone can help you.

Comment: I think you can try the when().otherwise() syntax, https://medium.com/@sparkcodegeeks/spark-case-when-and-when-otherwise-usage-spark-by-examples-e82259d62f91